# What is the order of crystal field stabilisation energy for tris(ethylenediamine)chromium(III) chloride and hexaaquachromium(III) chloride?

Tags: coordination-compounds, crystal-field-theory

In my book it is given that the crystal field stabilisation energy for $\ce{[Cr(en)3]Cl3}$ is more than that of the complex $\ce{[Cr(H2O)6]Cl3}.$ By what I have studied, the crystal field stabilisation energy depends on the number of electrons in $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ and $\mathrm{e_g}$ orbitals and the pairing energy.

The number of electrons in both the compounds is the same and both undergo octahedral splitting, so that term is same for both.

Now coming to pairing energy is the energy of $\ce{en}$ more than $\ce{H2O}$ since it is a chelating group? Or it depends upon the position of the ligands in the spectrochemical series?

Comment: it depends upon the position of the ligands in the spectrochemical series

Comment: Although the number of electrons are same in Eg and T2g orbitals though the ∆o is not same for both the ∆o for chelate ligands is > than that of normal ligands hence the CFSE OF FORMER IS MORE